# JSON-Parser written in Go

Tags: parsing, json, go

Below is a JSON parser written in Go. It's just a task I set myself in order to learn Go, which is also the rationale for reinventing this wheel. At the moment, it's not 100% complete but it can process quite some input already and also provide diagnostics on invalid inputs.

My questions concerning this code are:

- I have a strong background in C++ and PHP, so I'm concerned whether I took some best practices from there and used them here, which I shouldn't.
- Similarly, I wonder if some of the code is non-idiomatic Go code which could be improved.
- Another thing is correctness, in particular the correct use of Go features. I'm not so much interested in whether something is faulty concerning the parsing of JSON, I already know that it's not complete.
- One specific aspect I'm doubtful about is the use of channels to carry errors. It seemed like a smart idea to me, but I don't rule out that it's stupid after all.

In any case, I welcome suggestions how to improve.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

const (
    tNone = iota
    tRoot
    tComma
    tColon
    tObjectStart
    tObjectEnd
    tArrayStart
    tArrayEnd
    tString
    tNull
    tNumber
    tBool
)

// ErrInvalidToken signals that something could not be converted to a token.
var ErrInvalidToken = errors.New("invalid token")

// ErrInvalidStructure signals that a valid token was encountered in the wrong place.
// In particular, that means closing tokens (")", "}") outside the scope of the
// according aggregate value type. Further, it means commas outside of aggregate types
// and colons anywhere but as a separator between key and value of an object value.
var ErrInvalidStructure = errors.New("invalid structure")

// JSONElement is an element of the JSON syntax tree.
type JSONElement struct {
    tpe    int // type according to the t* constants above
    offset int // offset of the element within the input data
    parent int // index of the parent element in the output data
}

func findMatchingQuotes(data []byte, cur, length int) (int, error) {
    const (
        openingQuotes = iota
        character
        backslashEscaped
    )

    res := 0
    state := openingQuotes
    for {
        // get next glyph
        if cur+res == length {
            // no more data
            return 0, ErrInvalidToken
        }
        c := data[cur+res]

        switch state {
        case openingQuotes:
            switch c {
            case '"':
                // consume quotes
                res++
                state = character
            default:
                return 0, ErrInvalidToken
            }
        case character:
            switch {
            case c == '\\':
                // consume backslash
                res++
                state = backslashEscaped
            case c == '"':
                // consume closing quote and finish
                res++
                return res, nil
            case c < 32:
                // control byte
                return res, ErrInvalidToken
            default:
                // consume character
                res++
                state = character
            }
        case backslashEscaped:
            switch c {
            case '"', '\\', '/', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't':
                // consume character unseen
                res++
                state = character
            case 'u':
                // consume Unicode start marker
                res++
                // check next
                for i := 0; i != 4; i++ {
                    // get next glyph
                    if cur+res == length {
                        // no more data
                        return 0, ErrInvalidToken
                    }
                    switch data[cur+res] {
                    case '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F':
                        // consume hex digit
                        res++
                    default:
                        // invalid Unicode
                        return 0, ErrInvalidToken
                    }
                }
                state = character
            default:
                return 0, ErrInvalidToken
            }
        }
    }
}

func findEndOfNumber(data []byte, cur, length int) (int, error) {
    const (
        optionalSign = iota
        nonfractionStart
        nonfractionContinued
        radixSeparator
        fractionStart
        fractionContinued
        exponentSeparator
        exponentSign
        exponentStart
        exponentContinued
    )

    res := 0
    state := optionalSign
loop:
    for {
        // get next glyph
        if cur+res == length {
            break loop
        }
        c := data[cur+res]

        switch state {
        case optionalSign:
            // if it's a minus sign, skip it
            if c == '-' {
                res++
            }
            state = nonfractionStart

        case nonfractionStart:
            switch c {
            case '0':
                // consume non-fractional digit
                res++
                state = radixSeparator
            case '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9':
                // consume non-fractional digit
                res++
                state = nonfractionContinued
            default:
                break loop
            }

        case nonfractionContinued:
            switch c {
            case '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9':
                // consume non-fractional digits
                res++
                state = nonfractionContinued
            default:
                state = radixSeparator
            }

        case radixSeparator:
            switch c {
            case '.':
                // consume radix separator
                res++
                state = fractionStart
            default:
                state = exponentSeparator
            }

        case fractionStart:
            switch c {
            case '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9':
                // consume fractional digits
                res++
                state = nonfractionContinued
            default:
                break loop
            }

        case fractionContinued:
            switch c {
            case '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9':
                // consume fractional digits
                res++
            default:
                state = exponentSeparator
            }

        case exponentSeparator:
            switch c {
            case 'e', 'E':
                // consume exponent separator
                res++
                state = exponentSign
            default:
                break loop
            }

        case exponentSign:
            switch c {
            case '+', '-':
                // consume exponent sign
                res++
                state = exponentStart
            default:
                state = exponentStart
            }

        case exponentStart:
            // Note: It seems that "1.e01" is valid, although "01.2" isn't, hence the
            // numbers of the exponent are not parsed like the nonfractional digits.
            switch c {
            case '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9':
                // consume exponent digit
                res++
                state = exponentContinued
            default:
                break loop
            }
        case exponentContinued:
            switch c {
            case '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9':
                // consume exponent digit
                res++
                state = exponentContinued
            default:
                break loop
            }
        }
    }

    // check final state, there must not be incomplete parts
    switch state {
    case optionalSign, nonfractionStart, fractionStart, exponentSign, exponentStart:
        // incomplete number token
        return 0, ErrInvalidToken
    case nonfractionContinued, radixSeparator, fractionContinued, exponentSeparator, exponentContinued:
        return res, nil
    default:
        return 0, errors.New("invalid state parsing number")
    }
}

func parseJSON(data []byte) ([]JSONElement, error) {
    // create a channel to receive errors from
    exc := make(chan error)

    // start parsing in a goroutine which emits the resulting tokens to this channel
    tokens := make(chan JSONElement)
    go func() {
        // close error channel on exit to terminate waiting loop
        defer close(exc)

        length := len(data)
        cur := 0
        for cur != length {
            switch data[cur] {
            case ' ', '\n', '\r', '\t':
                fmt.Println(cur, "whitespace")
                // skip whitespace
                cur++
            case '{':
                fmt.Println(cur, "opening braces")
                tokens <- JSONElement{tpe: tObjectStart, offset: cur}
                cur++
            case '}':
                fmt.Println(cur, "closing braces")
                tokens <- JSONElement{tpe: tObjectEnd, offset: cur}
                cur++
            case '[':
                fmt.Println(cur, "opening brackets")
                tokens <- JSONElement{tpe: tArrayStart, offset: cur}
                cur++
            case ']':
                fmt.Println(cur, "closing brackets")
                tokens <- JSONElement{tpe: tArrayEnd, offset: cur}
                cur++
            case ':':
                fmt.Println(cur, "colon")
                tokens <- JSONElement{tpe: tColon, offset: cur}
                cur++
            case ',':
                fmt.Println(cur, "comma")
                tokens <- JSONElement{tpe: tComma, offset: cur}
                cur++
            case '"':
                fmt.Println(cur, "string")
                size, err := findMatchingQuotes(data, cur, length)
                if err != nil {
                    exc <- err
                    return
                }
                tokens <- JSONElement{tpe: tString, offset: cur}
                cur += size
            case 'n':
                fmt.Println(cur, "null")
                if cur+4 > length {
                    exc <- ErrInvalidToken
                    return
                }
                if (data[cur+1] != 'u') || (data[cur+2] != 'l') || (data[cur+3] != 'l') {
                    exc <- ErrInvalidToken
                }
                tokens <- JSONElement{tpe: tNull, offset: cur}
                cur += 4
            case 't':
                fmt.Println(cur, "true")
                if cur+4 > length {
                    exc <- ErrInvalidToken
                    return
                }
                if (data[cur+1] != 'r') || (data[cur+2] != 'u') || (data[cur+3] != 'e') {
                    exc <- ErrInvalidToken
                }
                tokens <- JSONElement{tpe: tBool, offset: cur}
                cur += 4
            case 'f':
                fmt.Println(cur, "false")
                if cur+5 > length {
                    exc <- ErrInvalidToken
                    return
                }
                if (data[cur+1] != 'a') || (data[cur+2] != 'l') || (data[cur+3] != 's') || (data[cur+4] != 'e') {
                    exc <- ErrInvalidToken
                }
                tokens <- JSONElement{tpe: tBool, offset: cur}
                cur += 5
            case '-', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9':
                fmt.Println(cur, "number")
                size, err := findEndOfNumber(data, cur, length)
                if err != nil {
                    exc <- err
                    return
                }
                tokens <- JSONElement{tpe: tNumber, offset: cur}
                cur += size
            default:
                fmt.Println(cur, "unexpected")
                exc <- ErrInvalidToken
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    res := make([]JSONElement, 0, 10)
    res = append(res, JSONElement{tpe: tRoot})
    context := 0
    for {
        select {
        case err := <-exc:
            // Note that "err" can be nil, which happens when the channel
            // is closed and it just means that the goroutine finished.
            fmt.Println("received error", err)
            return res, err
        case elem := <-tokens:
            fmt.Println("received element", elem)
            // determine context changes
            switch elem.tpe {
            case tArrayStart, tObjectStart:
                // remember parent index for aggregate value
                elem.parent = context
                context = len(res)
            case tArrayEnd:
                if res[context].tpe != tArrayStart {
                    // current context must be an array
                    return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                }
                // validate all intermediate tokens
                const (
                    start = iota // initial state, next token must be a value if present
                    comma        // next token must be a comma if present
                    next         // next token must be present and not a comma
                )
                state := start
                for i := context + 1; i != len(res); i++ {
                    t := res[i]
                    // if this is not a direct child, ignore it
                    if t.parent != context {
                        continue
                    }
                    // if this is the end of a nested structure, ignore it
                    if t.tpe == tObjectEnd || t.tpe == tArrayEnd {
                        continue
                    }

                    switch t.tpe {
                    case tObjectStart, tArrayStart, tBool, tNumber, tNull, tString:
                        if state == comma {
                            // expected a comma as separator, not a value
                            return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                        }
                        state = comma
                    case tComma:
                        if state != comma {
                            // expected a value, not a comma as separator
                            return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                        }
                        state = next
                    default:
                        // unexpected token as array element
                        return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                    }
                }
                if state == next {
                    // brackets are not empty but don't end in a value
                    return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                }
                context = res[context].parent
                elem.parent = context
            case tObjectEnd:
                if res[context].tpe != tObjectStart {
                    // current context must be an object
                    return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                }
                // validate all intermediate tokens
                const (
                    start = iota // initial state, next token must be a string if present
                    colon        // next token must be present and a colon
                    value        // next token must be present and a value
                    comma        // next token must be a comma if present
                    next         // next token must be present and be a string
                )
                state := start
                for i := context + 1; i != len(res); i++ {
                    t := res[i]
                    // if this is not a direct child, ignore it
                    if t.parent != context {
                        continue
                    }
                    // if this is the end of a nested structure, ignore it
                    if t.tpe == tObjectEnd || t.tpe == tArrayEnd {
                        continue
                    }

                    switch state {
                    case start, next:
                        if t.tpe != tString {
                            // expected a string as key
                            return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                        }
                        state = colon
                    case colon:
                        if t.tpe != tColon {
                            // expected a colon as separator
                            return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                        }
                        state = value
                    case value:
                        switch t.tpe {
                        case tObjectStart, tArrayStart, tBool, tNumber, tNull, tString:
                            state = comma
                        default:
                            // expected a value
                            return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                        }
                    case comma:
                        if t.tpe != tComma {
                            // expected a comma as separator
                            return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                        }
                        state = next
                    }
                }
                switch state {
                case colon, value, next:
                    // braces are not empty but don't end in a value
                    return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                }
                context = res[context].parent
                elem.parent = context
            case tComma:
                if res[context].tpe != tArrayStart && res[context].tpe != tObjectStart {
                    return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                }
                elem.parent = context
            case tColon:
                if res[context].tpe != tObjectStart {
                    return nil, ErrInvalidStructure
                }
                elem.parent = context
            default:
                elem.parent = context
            }
            res = append(res, elem)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code seems good.The error channel is a good idea.

Personally, the only change I would suggest is to use the Generator Pattern (something like this https://medium.com/@thejasbabu/concurrency-patterns-golang-5c5e1bcd0833) in the function "parseJSON" it will split the function into 2 and improve readability.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Using the generator pattern as in the inner functions makes sense. Its benefits are less though, because you need to structurally validate the whole (think matching paretheses) before you can return anything.